# How to make all windows except dialogs full screen in XFce?

Tags: xfce

Is there any way to setup XFce to set all windows to full screen by default, except for dialog windows and other windows that can only be small, in XFce?

Preferably this:

- Does not cover XFce's panel.
- Shows window decorations only for the dialogs and small windows, not for the full screen windows.

I tried switching to the Ratpoison window manager within XFce, but this made the XFce panel unusable and in the wrong place, and further did not give any special treatment for dialog windows.

Comment: I haven't personally used this but `maximus` might have some fine grained configuration for that?: https://launchpad.net/maximus

Comment: If you wanted to try ratpoison, you could also try XMonad. It has modules [including configurations for use with desktop elements that work out-of-the-box](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Config-Xfce.html). The dialogs float, but have no decorations (by default, because as XMonad is more like a framework to build your own WM, anything is possible).

Comment: Might I ask how you managed to run ratpoison from within xfce? It doesn't offer a --replace argument which seems to be the supported way of replacing a wm.

Answer (score 0):

Devil's Pie is perfect for this.

[Arch package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/devilspie/) and [Man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-devilspie/).

It lets you set detailed window matching rules, and then perform various actions. I use it to automatically move my email client to the left half of workspace 2 and my irc client to the right half to workspace 2.

If you want to set all normal windows to be maximized, you can do:

```
(if
  (wintype "normal")
  (maximize)
)
```

Replace `maximize` with `fullscreen` if that's what you really want. Or you could do:

```
(if
  (not 
    (wintype "dialog")
    (maximize)
  )
)
```

Or you can use `xprop` to get the exact window property and then use `window_property` to filter based on that. Basically you can do anything you want.